# jQuery hover after DOM change

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

this is how I use [**jQuery hover**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

> hover( handlerIn(eventObject),
>   handlerOut(eventObject) )

```
$(".box").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('baseColor', $this.css('background-color'));
    $this.hover(function() {
        $this.animate( {
            backgroundColor : "white"
        }, 50);
    }, function() {
        $this.animate( {
            backgroundColor : $this.data('baseColor')
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

The problem is when DOM changes the hover effect does not work anymore. I know the **live** method solved such problems many times for me but how do I solve it in that case?

Comment: Check out my answer, I identify the issue and I also link you to a script that might help you achieve your animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated
>   to a single numeric value, except as
>   noted below; most properties that are
>   non-numeric cannot be animated using
>   basic jQuery functionality. (For
>   example, width, height, or left can be
>   animated but background-color cannot
>   be.) Property values are treated as a
>   number of pixels unless otherwise
>   specified. The units em and % can be
>   specified where applicable.

Specifically `For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be.`

If you're trying just to update the background color to white, try:

```
 $this.hover(function() {
      $this.css('background-color', '#fff');
 }, function() {
      $this.css('background-color',$this.data('baseColor'));
 });
```

If you're trying to make the effect appear 50ms after the user hovers, try using [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Now if you're attempting a transition from the current color to white, you need to learn about color blending. But to save you the trouble here's an excellent [script by Michael Leigeber](http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/05/javascript-color-fading-script/). It supports background color fading.

---

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the real problem. I deleted my answer and voted you up.

Comment: +1 @Khez you're totally right of course! I forgot about that and assumed that the OP had working code which stops working on DOM updates. Good catch